# how can I limit downloaded file size in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to limit downloaded file size to only < 1MB files, but my code is somehow buggy because it downloads > 1MB, however, when I tried to test it downloads more than 1mb file

````
self.url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=filetype:{}+{}&num={}'.format(self.ext, self.magic_header, self.max)
self.MAX_SIZE = 1000000 # 1024 * 1024 this doesnt work either
try:
            response = requests.head(href)
            total = response.headers.get('content-length')
            if int(total) > self.MAX_SIZE:
              print "maximum size (%d kbs)" % (self.MAX_SIZE/1024)
            else:
              if total is None:
                pass
              else:
                #if os.path.exists(OUTPUT_DIR):
                #  print("Deleting old output directory")
                #  shutil.rmtree(OUTPUT_DIR)
                #print("Creating output directory")
                #os.mkdir(OUTPUT_DIR)
                os.system('wget -P %s %s'%(OUTPUT_DIR, href))
          except Exception as e:
            pass```
````

output

```
204K 'NetLogo Tutorial 1 in Spanish.pdf'  1.2M  zElquehacertutorial.pdf
916K  proceso_tutorial_de_la_mcdst.pdf    2.3M  z-El-sistema-tutorial-en-la-UV.pdf
```

Comment: Can you post the url from which you’re fetching the response?

Comment: Are you sure that the reported content length is accurate?

Comment: ready , and it gives me `350270` and `61920` which are `content-length`

Comment: Neither of those values look like they correspond to the actual file sizes, in which case the reported length is *not* accurate. Your code is working fine; it's the *input* which is the problem.

Comment: how a better way can I limit file size?

Comment: I'm guessing there's a redirect, so Content-Length is the size of the redirect message rather than the target. Check if the response code is 3xx to see if this is the case.

Comment: this the response https://gist.github.com/SkyBulk/ce53643360b56ad0a7c883f4f7f2e0dc , http code 200

Comment: That PDF is 350270 bytes, which is the correct value reported by Python and is less than 1MB.

Comment: check again https://gist.github.com/SkyBulk/ce53643360b56ad0a7c883f4f7f2e0dc, multiples one `Hojapadronal.pdf` 1.4Mb which is more than 1mb

Answer (score 0):

if you have the file object, you can use this

```
import os
os.fstat(f.fileno()).st_size > self.MAX_SIZE:
```

os.fstat(f.fileno()).st_size will give the file's size in byte